# Running Multiple programs at once from Windows Run Dialog Box

Tags: windows-7, windows, run-dialog

I like to open many programs from the Run dialog box. I need a way to be able to start multiple programs from one single use of the Run box.

Though the question is straightforward, yet for any confusion clarification whatsoever - I open Google Chrome, Outlook and Visual Studio from the Run dialog box by typing `chrome`, `outlook` and `devenv` one at a time. So i need a way to be able to run all three of them in one go.

I tried giving the input as `chrome; outlook; devenv` and it failed. I tried `chrome, devenv, outlook` and it failed too.

**Update:**
Problem with the first and obvious solution of **Writing a batch file** is that it is hard coded. So I can't start a new combination of programs now. I created a batch file `dgc` for opening devenv, chrome and outlook at the same time. But this time i wanted to open vlc media player too along with the previous three programs. This makes the batch file idea not so useful.

Further, if it was possible to run that batch file along with vlc by doing something along the lines of `dgc; vlc;`, then i could start the previous three programs AND vlc media player all at the same time.

Anyone knows the right way?

Comment: Make a batch file to run them then run that from the run dialog.

Comment: @EBGreen : Thanks. It was the first and most straightforward method that came to my mind. I will update my question to let you know what the problem with that is.

Comment: This works: `cmd /c start notepad & start calc & start taskmgr` I don't know if it's an acceptable solution for you, though.

Comment: @and31415: Liked your answer. Good to know one more way. Thanks.

Comment: @and31415 good answer :) never even crossed my mind to run that.. my dirty hack-n-bash mind went straight to vbscript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

You have a couple of options though.  If you are always going to want to open the same group of programs, you could wrie a simple batch file which you can call from run (which will in turn spawn all programs).

If you have a changing or dynamic list - you could write a piece of vbscript which takes all arguments passed to the script and opens them as arguments - like so:

```
Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
For Each strArg in objArgs
  WshShell.Run(strArg)
Next
```

> Usage: myscript.vbs calc cmd mspaint explorer

if this errors you can always add `on error resume next` to the top of the script to only run valid commands.  If you have any spaces in program names or paths, these would need to be wrapped in "quotes"

EDIT:
If you create a registry key at: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\run.exe` and give it a `default reg_sz` value of `C:\windows\system32\runapps.vbs` and then place your file in theat location - you can launch a run prompt and use `run mspaint calc winword`.. which will save you a few characters:
[image: Example] (in this case a.vbs is the script i wrote for you earlier)

Comment: @displayName - assuming this worked as you accepted my answer?  Hopefully this will do everything you need it to :)

Comment: I accepted your answer to give you +15.. :D  (kidding). I accepted your answer because it is right. It is not the perfect solution though (and that is why i did not up-vote it). I don't want to be creating a script and then calling it. Not worth writing those extra characters for calling the script only to run `vlc; cmd;`.

Comment: see update (on its way) for how to simplify this... thats got to be worth an upvote if nothing else is ;)  if you plan to launch more than 3 apps, this actually saves you characters!

Comment: really appreciate your answer. That was useful. You get your deserving up-vote. :D

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help :)  Always nice when you can fudge it to work the way you want it to (or close enough)